# BigQuery getQueryResults always returning the same pageToken

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using the BigQuery API v2 to run a SQL query with the query job with maxResults set to 1000.
Then, from its response I get the jobId, and pageToken and execute the getQueryResult job to fetch the table rows from this two parameters.

The problem is that, the getQueryResult response contains the same pageToken param that is sent in the query param. So I am not able to paginate and my code runs in an infinite loop.

Is the getQueryResult the right place to get the next pageToken from or am I missing something ? Thanks in advance !

Here's the used API: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults

Comment: issue might be in your code rather than in logic that you described which is correct one

Comment: Does the job id need to be updated too ?

Comment: can you paste some code?

Comment: nope - getQueryResults retrieves the results of a query job that was already run - so it is the same jobid

Comment: In my first query I set the maxResults to 1k and also in the getQueryResults calls, would this be the problem ?

Comment: as Felipe suggested - post you code so someone will be able to help you :o) meantime have in mind that when last page is returned  - NextToken should be null

Comment: yes of course, but I think that page tokens are distinct ? Aren't them ?

Comment: Well, I got this, the pageTokens are very similar and could be treated as identical with the human eyes (which occured to me actually) ! But, in reality, they are not the same ! Anyway, thank you again guys for the support